# gorilla/websocket read tcp myWhiteIp:2206->clientIp: read: connection reset by peer

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm using gorilla websocket and have problems with connection.

It works perfectly with wifi connection, but with cellular data (3G, 4G) it is not connection with following error:

read tcp myWhiteIp:2206->clientIp: read: connection reset by peer

Please HELP!

Comment: The destination IP, is it internal to your wifi network?